# Animated pseudo elements and z-index - works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, z-index, pseudo-element

In firefox pseudo elements are behind the div (this is what I wanted to achieve) but in chrome they are on top. Is this a bug in chrome? Anyone knows how to fix this? Adding z-index to the div didn't help me to solve this problem.

I've also tried to apply some styles to div:hover but then when I hover over the div element it falls behind pseudo elements (in Firefox, in Chrome pseudo elements are already on top).

Demo on codepen https://codepen.io/mariuszdaniel/pen/rzdyRV?editors=1100

```css
@keyframes spin {
 from {
  transform: rotate(0turn)
             translateY(-100%) translateY(50%)
             rotate(1turn)
 }
 to {
  transform: rotate(1turn)
             translateY(-100%) translateY(50%)
             rotate(0turn);
 }
}

@keyframes spin-rev {
 from {
  transform: rotate(1turn)
             translateY(-100%) translateY(50%)
             rotate(0turn)
 }
 to {
  transform: rotate(0turn)
             translateY(-100%) translateY(50%)
             rotate(1turn);
 }
}

@keyframes glow {
 from {
  filter: blur(100px);
  opacity:  0.8
 }
 to {
  filter:  blur(200px);
  opacity: 0.4;
 }
}

.path { 
 width:300px; 
 height: 300px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/300);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 transition:  transform 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.path:hover {
 transform: scale(1.25);
 box-shadow:  0 0 50px 0 #3333;
}

.path::before, .path::after  {
 content: "";
 position:aboslute;
 display: block;
 width: 75%;
 height: 75%;
 margin: 25% auto 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
  /*filter: blur(100px); */
 /*opacity: 0.5;*/
}
 
.path::before  {
 /*mix-blend-mode:  hue;*/
 z-index: -200;
 background-color: #21D4FD;
 background-image: linear-gradient(19deg, #21D4FD 0%, #B721FF 100%);
 animation: spin 9s infinite /*alternate*/ linear, glow 3s infinite alternate linear;
}

.path::after {
 margin-top: -100%;
 z-index: -100;
 background-color: #08AEEA;
 background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #08AEEA 0%, #2AF598 100%);
 animation: spin-rev 6s infinite /*alternate-reverse*/ linear, glow 6s infinite alternate linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="path"></div>
```

Comment: I made a pen that looks like it's fixing your problem: https://codepen.io/joseph-mueller/pen/YxaVLO?editors=1100.

I just got rid of the the after elements with the assumption that chrome renders those on top of the div path because of rendering order.

Comment: Removing one of pseudo-elements helps but I would like to use two pseudo elements rather than one. Thanks.